# How to configure emacs' M-f and M-b to behavior like eclipse's Ctrl+right and Ctrl+left?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm from eclipse to emacs, and don't used to the behavior of <kbd>M-f</kbd> and <kbd>M-b</kbd>.

See the following javascript code:

```
module.controller('Front', ['$scope', function($scope){
```

When I use <kbd>Ctrl+right</kbd>, the cursor will jump to the `|` in the code:

```
|module|.|controller|('|Front|', |['|$scope|', |function|(|$scope|){|
```

and when I use <kbd>Ctrl+left</kbd>, the cursor will jump from right to left in these `|` positions.

But in emacs, M-f is different:

```
module|.controller|('Front|', ['$scope|', function|($scope|){
```

How to configure emacs to let M-f is exactly the same as eclipse's <kbd>Ctrl+right</kbd>, and <kbd>M-b</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Ctrl+left</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these functions do what you want:

```
(defun eclipse-forward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((go-back (looking-at-p "\\W")))
    (forward-word)
    (when go-back
      (backward-word))))

(defun eclipse-backward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((go-forward (looking-at-p "\\<")))
    (backward-word)
    (when go-forward
      (forward-word))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-left>") 'eclipse-backward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-right>") 'eclipse-forward-word)
```